# Script interface to install an arbitrary files to all nodes in Websphere?

Tags: java, websphere, wsadmin

I'm rather new to wsadmin and the administration client available for Websphere. I was wondering if anyone had an example of deploying arbitrary files to every Node in a Cell? Ideally I am looking for a solution that would work with both Websphere ND v7 and v6.1, and would not resort to native file transfer methods (e.g. windows shares / sftp), although if there is configuration that could be discovered through the Deployment Manager as to what native method to take to deploy the file that could be an option.

For some background, I'm trying to script the installation of an application for our clients. As part of that I will need to create a JDBC provider and a shared library along with my Application. IBM's documentation is fairly clear on how to create [shared library with a particular classpath](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_library.html), and a [JDBC Provider](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_configjdbc.html), and Websphere variables. But I am running into the problem of how I should go about ensuring that the resources defined on the classpaths of the configured provider and shared library are available on each Node at runtime?

Comment: Are you looking at ways to transfer the .jar files that are part of your JDBC provider and shared library so that they are present in all the machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arbitrary files can be managed centrally using `wsadmin`'s [`AdminConfig`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_adminconfig1.html) object. This approach places the files in WAS's configuration repository which is monitored by the node synchronization service, and therefore automatically synchronizes file changes from the master repository with each node repository. There are existing `wsadmin` commands that enable the files to be added, updated, and deleted centrally and remotely.

Here is some example `wsadmin` `jython` code which will upload a local file (`/temp/jdbc-driver.jar`) to the configuration repository (`<WAS_PROFILE_ROOT>/config/test-app/jdbc-driver.jar`). The node synchronization may be explicitly invoked as demonstrated in the script, or the synchronization will occur automatically if automatic synchronization is enabled.

```
file = "/temp/jdbc-driver.jar"
dest = "test-app/jdbc-driver.jar"
AdminConfig.createDocument(dest, file)
AdminNodeManagement.syncActiveNodes()
```

The following `wsadmin` `jython` code demonstrates how to update the file.

```
file = "/temp/jdbc-driver.jar"
dest = "test-app/jdbc-driver.jar"
digest = AdminConfig.extract(dest, file)
# update the file locally in /temp/jdbc-driver.jar
AdminConfig.checkin(dest, file, digest)
AdminNodeManagement.syncActiveNodes()
```

Comment: Thanks @shelley! I gave this a shot and it seems to be exactly what I was looking for. It seems that AdminNodeManagement seems to only be available on my WAS 7 box (not on the 6.1 box), but I think I have an example of a different way to force a configuration sync.